# JpaRepository vs EntityManager

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

If I have a service class that extends JpaRepository which extends CrudRepository and I am doing the CRUD just as fine in my service class, do I need to use EntityManager? Is there any advantage in using EntityManager over JpaRepository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the JPA repository you get some useful built-in CRUD methods and don't need to worry about EntityManager.

The only rare case where I sometimes have to use EntityManager is when I am writing unit tests for repository code.

Answer (score 0):

`Repository` is an abstraction over `EntityManager`. It shields developers from some complex details that are introduced with `EntityManager` and adds boilerplate code and many convenient methods.

`javax.persistence.EntityManager` is associated with a persistence context. Spring has its own interface which extends `CrudRepository` called `JpaRepository` for this purposes.